# Call of function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm having a problem with the `this` element in the code below

I'm trying to call a function in two way's but the second way dosen't work:

The function validate_email is not responding, I think the call for it is wrong in the second example.

**The working way is:**

```
checking = {};
checking.form = function(){
    return{

validate_mail: function(a){
    var c=true;
    var email_filter = /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+([\.]+([\w]+[\.])?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i;
    if( $.trim(a)!=""  && !$.trim(a).match(email_filter) )
    c=false;
    return c;
},
check_mail: function(div_id, error) {

        var email = $(div_id + ' input[name=email]').val();
        var check = this.validate_mail(email);
        if(check==false && $(div_id).is(':visible') )
         {
            $(div_id + ' '+ error).html('<b>some error</b>');   
        } else {
            $(div_id + ' ' + error).text('');
        }

    }
 }
}();


$(function(){
    $('#register input[name=email]').blur(function(){
         checking.form.check_mail("#register", ".error_email");
         });
}
```

**The not working way is:**

```
checking = {};
checking.form = function(){
    return{

validate_mail: function(a){
    var c=true;
    var email_filter = /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+([\.]+([\w]+[\.])?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i;
    if( $.trim(a)!=""  && !$.trim(a).match(email_filter) )
    c=false;
    return c;
},
check_mail: function(div_id, error) {
            return function(){ //**made the change  nr. 1**

        var email = $(div_id + ' input[name=email]').val();
        var check = this.validate_mail(email);
        if(check==false && $(div_id).is(':visible') )
         {
            $(div_id + ' '+ error).html('<b>some error</b>');   
        } else {
            $(div_id + ' ' + error).text('');
        }
      }
    }
 }
}();


$(function(){ //**made the change nr. 2**
    $('#register input[name=email]').blur(   
         checking.form.check_mail("#register", ".error_email")
        );

}
```

I need some help with this. I believe I'm not useing the `this` element in the right way

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: How can we help you if we don't even know what the code is supposed to do and what you want it to do?

Comment: The function validate_email is not responding, I think the call for it is wrong in the second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return the anonymous function, `this` doesn't refer to the owner object. you can store the value of `this` in some variable before returning the function and use it instead of this:

```
...
var that = this;

return function(){
  that.validate_mail(...);
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

`this.validate_mail(email);`

use

`checking.form.validate_mail(email);` it should work fine.

You cannot use `this` in your case because you are not creating an instance.

Comment: checking.form.validate_mail (small typo in your answer)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your way of coding is abit strange and makes it easy to make mistakes, this is also where the fault lies.
`this` is not known inside the anonymous function inside the check_mail function.

I would rewrite your code as the following to make it more clear:

```
var checking = {
    form: {
        validate_mail: function(a){
            var c=true;
            var email_filter = /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+([\.]+([\w]+[\.])?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i;
            if( $.trim(a)!=""  && !$.trim(a).match(email_filter) )
                c=false;
            return c;
        },
        check_mail: function(div_id, error) {
            var email = $(div_id + ' input[name=email]').val();
            var check = this.validate_mail(email);
            if(check==false && $(div_id).is(':visible') )
            {
                $(div_id + ' '+ error).html('<b>some error</b>');   
            } else {
                $(div_id + ' ' + error).text('');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$('#register input[name=email]').blur(function () {
    checking.form.check_mail("#register", ".error_email"); 
});
```

Comment: How should the call of the  function look in this case??

Comment: As so: `$('#register input[name=email]').blur(function () { checking.form.check_mail("#register", ".error_email"); });`
Notice the extra anonymous function.

Instead of creating function that return functions that you can use to bind, rather make the functions that do, and call them from anonymous functions that you use when binding to events.